# Clearing ADF Cache

Tags: oracle-adf

I have an application with say 2 pages. I enter values into the 1st page hit the enter button and some validation error occurs. Now instead of fixing the validation errors I go to the next page and make some valid entry and then hit entry I am getting the error messages from the first page. How to do I handle  this? 
If I set ClearCacheOnRollback to true for my appModule, what is actually happening? Once clear when does the cache get repopulated?

We are using unbounded taskflows. I have two master pages one creating different regions in a country, the second to create different govt schools these are separate jsf pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour because both your pages are sharing the same Application Module instance.

If you are using pages (not fragments), you will have to place each page in a different **isolated task flows** . Each isolated task flow will have its own Application Module instance - therefore its own cache. You can get an excellent explanation of how task flow transactions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/adf-task-flow-trans-fund-v1-1-1864319.pdf).

If you are using fragments (and UI Shell, for example), additionally to all above, you might need to add ExceptionMode="Immediate" attribute to your "BC4JDataControl" tags inside DataBindings.cpx file.

Setting ClearCacheOnRollback="true" is relevant only when rolling back the transaction. In practice, the only reason I've seen this flag being used is to produce "[Rollback and preserve current row behaviour](http://andrejusb.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/adf-rollback-and-keep-current-row.html)"

Comment: Can you please update your question with more details about how your general architecture: e.g. if you are using fragments, what exactly you do to open two pages, are pages part of the same task flow, etc

Comment: edited my answer with ClearCacheOnRollback explanation

Comment: You can't use unbounded task flows. You need ISOLATED bounded task flows for this to work.

Comment: Is there another solution?

Comment: My suggestion is to get rid of pages in unbounded task flows.
The entire ADF concept sits on top of bounded task flows. Unbounded task flows are for "HelloWorld" applications only. You need to 'Think in task flows', not in pages, when working with ADF.

Comment: Is there a work around.. lot of work has already gone into this.. am short of time.

Comment: Hard to say, You can try to use goLink, or goButton as navigation between those two pages. goButton will force the second page to create a new Application Module, therefore a new transaction. But that's hardly best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I resoled this issue by the following.. included this code to my EntityImpl classes..

```
public void validateEntity()
```

{
    try
    {
      super.validateEntity();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      this.refresh(EntityImpl.REFRESH_UNDO_CHANGES);
      this.getDBTransaction().rollback();
    }
  }

Hope this will be helpful for someone ..

Comment: If you have an exception, you won't get rid of the problem by simply catching and  hiding the exception. Careful with such aproaches.